# Require Once Always Not Found even if Link is correct in PHP

Tags: php

I have a class file named Notes.php .It does have a `namespace` and when I do `require_once` it gives me a Warning Required file not found  where as the url is correct and also. Below is the Class File

Directory tree is:

```
Class
    Notes
        Notes.php
    Database
        Db.php
```

Below is the class code

```
#Declare Namespace for the Notes class
namespace Dashboard\Api\Notes;

require_once '../Database/Db.php';

use Dashboard\Api\Database\Db;

class Notes {

    # Set Protected Properties
    protected $_db;
    public $username;

    function __construct () {
        $this->_db = Db::getInstance();
    }

    public function getNotes() {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM notes";
        $result = $this->_db->query($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about mixed '/' and '\' ?

Comment: DIdn't get your point..

Comment: in your require_once, there are both \ and / (see your comment on @yergo answer). It does not crash, it's just a notice... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `__DIR__`:

```
require_once( __DIR__ . '\..\Database\Db.php');
```

It may happen because you are using some `.htaccess` configurations etc.

Other useful constants: [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Comment: It gives 

Warning: require_once(C:\Program Files (x86)\XAMPP 5.6.3 PHP\htdocs\Mobile Diary\Dashboard\api\class\Notes../Database/Db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\XAMPP 5.6.3 PHP\htdocs\Mobile Diary\Dashboard\api\class\Notes\Notes.php on line 12

Comment: Thx a lot .. It worked like a charm dude.. Just can you explain me what was wrong earlier the forward slashes??

Comment: yep, missing slash after `__DIR__`

Comment: Windows differs with Unix-like with files patches. When using MS you should use rather `\ `, at (i guess ANY) other system, you're required to use `/` but I'm not 100% confident if it is still actual, because I was working on MS quite few years ago.